# Colloquial name for "natural fibre ropes"; picture included

Tags: word-request

1. What's the natural fiber [rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope) colloquially called?
2. And what about the synthetic fiber one, what is it called too?

[image: natural fiber rope]

Comment: I believe that this will mostly depend on the material, e.g. *nylon*, *linen*. A few simple words I can think of are *twine*, *yarn*, and maybe *thread*. But a *thread* would be small. You picture makes me think of *hawser*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no distinct English words in common usage for *rope* made from one fiber or another. When necessary to specify it, the material is added as an attributive, whether natural or synthetic:

- nylon rope
- jute rope
- Kevlar rope
- silk rope
- manila rope

and so on. The same applies for terms for rope based on size or construction, such as *twine* or *cord* or *webbing*.

Certain terms are associated with a particular *use* of rope, for which one material might be inferred, but you cannot apply that term to a different use— one person's mooring line and another person's climbing rope may both be made of woven nylon, but they refer to different tools for different uses.